# Extracting numeric data from Excel column and convert into to array of strings in Python

Tags: python, spyder

I have data in excel sheet which is arranged like this :
[image]

I want to write a python code in Spyder to extract the 2nd column of this data in this form :

data1 = `["66","55","33","22"]`

How can I do this? I am doing this using xlrd.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that the variable that stores your sheet is 'sheet' you can do follow:

```
second_col_data_arr = sheet.col_values(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it works out, but I want each array value to be a string. Right now, I am getting this output.           second_col_data_arr =  [55.0, 66.0, 55.0, 33.0, 22.0], but I want this to be                      second_col_data_arr =  ['55.0', '66.0', '55.0', '33.0', '22.0']

Comment: Well, I just found out that I can do this to covert each numeric value into a string. alpha = list(map(str,var)), where var = [66.0, 55.0, 33.0, 22.0] and alpha returns me ['66.0', '55.0', '33.0', '22.0']